# Django ModelForm does not save to database

Tags: django, django-forms

I try to add a comment but it does not save it to the database. There is no error.

My Views is

```
def add_comment(request, id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST,instance=article)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return redirect('articles:detail', pk=article.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    template="article/comment.html"
    return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

**comment.html:**

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('name', 'comment')
```

Comment: is the view redirecting to `articles:detail` or returning to `article/comment.html`?

Comment: You're checking if the form is valid, and doing nothing if it isn't. So if something is wrong, you're not going to get an error and it isn't going to save.

Comment: Can you please add the code for your `CommentForm`?

Comment: article/comment.html not working , error is page not fount . i added CommentForm .

Comment: i changed comment.post to comment.article then it fixed

Comment: You are passing instance of article into CommentForm. That is not right